# System.UnauthorizedAccessException occurs under Admin privileges with full access to folder

Tags: c#, .net

I'm all out of ideas on fixing an "Access Denied" issue on Windows 8.1...

I'm building a console app in Visual Studio under Administrative mode and my app is simply trying to do the following:

```
using System.IO;

namespace CommandCenterScriptLauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The argument passed was " + args[0] + ".");
                Console.ReadLine();
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Matt\Music\target", "TEXT FILE BODY WITH ARG: " + args[0]);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No arguments were passed.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\Matt\\Music\\target", "TEXT FILE BODY WITH NO ARGS");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not only am I running in Admin mode which isn't helping, but the folder itself is NOT read only, and ALL USERS on the Security tab for the target folder have been granted FULL CONTROL.

What else am I missing here?!

Comment: What is target, a file or a folder?

Comment: This is in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx). UnauthorizedAccessException: *path* specified a directory.

Comment: Just a suggestion outside of your specific issue, you should do if(args.Length>0) instead of a blind try/catch, as if the File.WriteAllText creates an exception(like in your situation) the catch will also cause an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in a filename to `File.WriteAllText`.  Right now, it looks like you are trying to write to a directory.  That won't work.

Comment: Yes very obvious syntax error on my end. For some reason the exception thrown by the Windows Operating System blames the Permissions and User Access.

Not sure if this was unintentional or by design...

Comment: If the exact exception that you got was `UnauthorizedAccessException`, then it was by design.  As `mike z` points out in his comment, the documentation is clear about throwing that exception when you try to write to a directory.  I'll repaste the doc link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write in another location?. Windows for some reason prevent for writing on system folders. Try something like 'c:/Test/yourFile.txt'.

Check also UAC is disabled.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer.